# Is it possible to decode non-homogenous arrays using Swift/Codable?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I need to decode JSON data in a array where the first element is a different object from all the following objects.  I would like to throwaway the first array element and decode the rest.  Is this possible with Swift Codable?

Here is a example I put together in Swift Playground that illustrates what is happening

```
import Foundation
class Test: Codable {
    var name:String = ""
    var number:Int = -1
}
var json1 = """
[[{"Type":"Testing", "Name":23}],
[{"name":"Rec1", "number":2}],
[{"name":"Rec2", "number":3}]]
"""
var json2 = """
[[{"name":"Rec12", "number":22}],
[{"name":"Rec22", "number":32}]]
"""
do{
    let test1 = try JSONDecoder().decode([[Test]].self, from: json1.data(using: .utf8)!)
    for t in test1 {
        print("\(t[0].name) \(t[0].number)")
    }
}catch{
    print("Exception thrown 1: \(error)")
}
do{
    let test2 = try JSONDecoder().decode([[Test]].self, from: json2.data(using: .utf8)!)
    for t in test2 {
        print("\(t[0].name) \(t[0].number)")
    }
}catch{
    print("Exception thrown 2: \(error)")
}
```

The output is unsurprising.  Decoding `json1` throws a exception, decoding `json2` does not:

```
Exception thrown 1: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"name\", intValue: nil) (\"name\").", underlyingError: nil))
Rec12 22
Rec22 32
```

I have no control over this data, I cannot ask the suppliers to be nicer - if only.

The only way forward I can see is to do text processing on the JSON data before I give it to JSONDecoder.  I am new to Swift, I am hoping there is a better way than this....

```
private func _hackJSONArray(_ input:Data) throws -> Data {
    /*
     Input data is of the form:
     [
       [{"Type":"Testing", "Name":23}],
       [{"name":"Rec1", "number":2}],
       [{"name":"Rec2", "number":3}]
     ]
     
     That is the first element is not like the others
     */
    var instr = String(data:input, encoding:.utf8)!
    if instr.prefix(2) != "[[" {
        throw ErrorItem(theErrorType: .InvalidJSON(instr), theDescription: "Failed to decode JSON data.  Did not start with: \"[[\"")
    }
    if let endOfFirstElement = instr.firstIndex(of: "]") {
        let first = instr.index(instr.startIndex, offsetBy:1)
        let last = instr.index(endOfFirstElement, offsetBy: 2)
        instr.removeSubrange(first..<last)
    }else{
        throw ErrorItem(theErrorType: .InvalidJSON(instr), theDescription: "Failed to decode JSON data.  Could not find: \"]\"")
    }
    return instr.data(using: .utf8)!
}
```

Comment: An array of arrays of just one element?

Comment: Yes, in the example here.  The actual data I am dealing with is perverse in a lot of ways.  This is a toy example for just one of the problems

Comment: Hard to help if the problem isn’t honestly presented...

Answer (score 1):

To cope with the variable data structure you'll have to write your own decoder for the test type along with a CodingKeys enum that defines the possible fields.  The approach is to try to decode for one of the possible fields, and if that fails catch the error and in the catch block try to decode for the other possibility:

```
class Test: Decodable {
   let name: String
   let number: Int
   
   enum CodingKeys:  String, CodingKey{
      case other = "Type".   //required as Type is a reserved keyword, so can't be an enum case
      case Name
      case name
      case number
      
   }
      
   required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      do {
         name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .other)
      } catch {
         name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
      }
      
      do {
         number = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .Name)
      } catch {
         number = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .number)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What you are saying, if I understand, is that to cope with a non-homogeneous array, treat it like a homogeneous array of the union of all objects in it, where each field is effectively optional.

Comment: @Worik not quite.  I'm treating the keys as variable rather than the data itself; in this example all the array objects are still of the OP's Test type, just they are keyed in different ways in the JSON.  If the data itself was non-homogenous it would need a different approach, and for that I'd probably use a data structure with enums and associated values (you could use multiple optional data types but that would be messy longer term)

Answer (score 0):

So, flanker's answer is an elegant one. But the problem is that it's filling the first array's element with incorrect data. The author said that it should be more likely thrown away than being mapped. So in my view not an elegant but straight-forward solution is to declare your data structure fields as `Optional`:

```swift
struct Test: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var number: Int?
}
```

And then just check your result for nil values:

```swift
testArray.filter({obj in
    return obj.name == nil ? false : true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to toss the invalid elements, and Swift supports decoding of optionals so just make generic wrapper that can turn any array of `Element` into an array of `Element?`, decode an array of the wrapped type and then throw out any nil values by using `compactMap`.

For example:

```
let jsonData =
"""
[
{"name": "a"},
{"name": "b"},
{"malformed": 1 },
{"name": "c"},
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct ThingToDecode: Decodable {
  var name: String
}

struct OptionalElement<WrappedDecodable: Decodable> : Decodable {
  var value: WrappedDecodable?
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    value = try? container.decode(WrappedDecodable.self)
  }
}

let decoded = (try! JSONDecoder().decode([OptionalElement<ThingToDecode>].self, from: jsonData)).compactMap(\.value)

print(decoded)
```

Note that if you actually wanted the heterogeneous types, then you can use an enum to preserve all of the elements.  In such a case you can write it yourself, but its much faster to just paste it into QuickType.io and it will actually code gen the enum for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make properties as optional in model. And filter the non-nil elements of `[Test]` array. This approach still decodes all the properties including the unformatted ones `Name`, `Type` and removes them after filtering the array.

```
struct Test: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var number: Int?
}

var json1 = """
[
[{"Type":"Testing", "Name":23}],
[{"name":"Rec1", "number":2}],
[{"Type":"Testing", "Name":23}],
[{"name":"Rec2", "number":3}],
[{"Type":"Testing", "Name":23}]
]
"""

    do{
        let test1 = try JSONDecoder().decode([[Test]].self, from: json1.data(using: .utf8)!)
        let result = test1.filter { $0.first?.name != nil }
        print(result)
    } catch {
        print("Exception thrown 1: \(error)")
    }
```

Console:

```
[[TestProject5.Test(name: Optional("Rec1"), number: Optional(2))], [TestProject5.Test(name: Optional("Rec2"), number: Optional(3))]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One good trick that worked for me was to use an intermediate enum for encoding and decoding the array of multiple subclasses.

Let's say we have these two classes Rectangle, Circle, inheriting from the same base Shape. We also have an class that contains an array of these shapes. We would like to encode this class without giving up the heteregenous character of the array.

```
class Shape {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Circle: Shape {
    var radius: Float

    init(radius: Float, name: String) {
        self.radius = radius
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}

class Rectangle: Shape {
    var length: Float
    var width: Float

    init(length: Float, width: Float, name: String) {
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}

class Scene : Codable {
    var shapes: [Shape]
}
```

Encoding and decoding can be done by converting these subclasses to enum cases, but we want to preserve the class structure.

Instead we can encode this array with an intermediate enum that envelopes these subclasses. Let's call this ShapeDTO and declare it as codable:

```
enum ShapeDTO : Codable {
    case circle(_: Circle)
    case rectangle(_: Rectangle)
}
```

Once we have this enum all we have to do is to add custom encoders and decoders to the classes to map the data through an array of ShapeDTO enums. Here's the final code:

```
class Shape: Codable {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Circle: Shape {
    var radius: Float

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case radius
    }

    init(radius: Float, name: String) {
        self.radius = radius
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.radius = try container.decode(Float.self, forKey: .radius)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }

    override public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(radius, forKey: .radius)
        try super.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}

class Rectangle: Shape {
    var length: Float
    var width: Float

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case length
        case width
    }

    init(length: Float, width: Float, name: String) {
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.length = try container.decode(Float.self, forKey: .length)
        self.width = try container.decode(Float.self, forKey: .width)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }

    override public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(length, forKey: .length)
        try container.encode(width, forKey: .width)
        try super.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}

enum ShapeDTO : Codable {
    case circle(_: Circle)
    case rectangle(_: Rectangle)
}

class Scene : Codable {

    var shapes: [Shape]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case shapes
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let shapeDTOs = try container.decode([ShapeDTO].self, forKey: .shapes)
        var shapes = [Shape]()
        for dto in shapeDTOs {
            if case let .circle(circle) = dto {
                shapes.append(circle)
            }
            else if case let .rectangle(rectangle) = dto {
                shapes.append(rectangle)
            }
        }
        self.shapes = shapes
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        var shapeDTOs: [ShapeDTO] = shapes.map {
            if $0 is Circle { return .circle($0 as! Circle) }
            if $0 is Rectangle { return .rectangle($0 as! Rectangle) }
            assert(false, "Unknown shape!")
        }
        try container.encode(shapeDTOs, forKey: .shapes)
    }
}
```